# Search for a certain numerical value after a fixed pattern in Notepad++and remove everything else

Tags: pattern-matching, notepad++

I am trying to search for a numerical value after a certain Pattern Match using Notepad++ and  remove everything else except the value and pattern.

I am unable to figure out a effective solution to this. The log file in concern is huge.

Below is an snippet of the log file containing the pattern I am trying to match.

The Pattern 'Net:' is what I am trying to match and pick the value immediately after it and remove everything else.Any help regarding this will be deeply appreciated. You will see `Net:` on the 2nd and on the 4th line.

Line to Delete Line to Delete Line to Delete Line to Delete Line to Delete Line to Delete
Data to delete Net:5770 Data to delete Data to delete Data to delete 
Line to Delete Line to Delete Line to Delete Line to Delete Line to Delete Line to Delete
Data to delete Net:5770 Data to delete Data to delete Data to delete 
Line to Delete Line to Delete Line to Delete Line to Delete Line to Delete Line to Delete

Comment: Can you please add the expected results, if you use the above sample as an input?

Comment: Hi nl-x,
The expected result for the above sample as input would be as below:
Net:5770
Net:5770 and so on...
Sorry for not posting it earlier. new to stackoverflow too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to do this. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the "Find/Replace" box - in the bottom left, choose "Regular Expression" radio button. In the "Find What" box put

```
.*(Net:[\d]+).*
```

Explanation: `.*` matches any character 0 or more times; `(...)` means store the whatever matches inside these parentheses, `Net:` are the first characters to match, then `[\d]+` means match any digit one or more times, and finally `.*` again means match any character (except newline) zero or more times. In the "Replace With" box put

```
\1
```

This means take the first group that was saved in the "Find What" box and place it here. Then click "Replace". You can choose "Replace All" once you're sure it does what you want.

Output:

```
<14>Jun 20 02:13:31 syslog: 7984220 64934      |7984220    |MEAL   |sess_id:37550, AVinDataMsgs:[0] TotAVinData:[0] AVoutDataMsgs:[63] TotAVoutData:[3870720]            |meal_sess_logger                              |1662 |DBG  
Net:5770
<14>Jun 20 02:13:31 syslog: 7984680 64936      |7984680    |SSMC   |WM's SET 6050 B 349, G 267, Y 184, R 15                                                              |ssm_asf_watermark_calc                        |702  |CRI  
Net:5770
<14>Jun 20 02:13:31 syslog: 7984680 64938      |7984680    |SSMC   |sess_id:37550 RUP:20000 Kbps, Enc_bitrate:5909 Kbps, RDP:5000 Kbps                                   |ssm_update_res_chg_counter                    |789  |DBG
```

Comment: @user3058854 If one or the other solution works, can you mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark under the up-down arrows? This way, the community knows your question has been resolved. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Done...Sorry for not noticing it earlier...I am able to check only one answer here although both the solutions worked for me...

Comment: @user3058854 You should choose whichever worked better for you, however you want to define that :-) No problems at all!

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, go to replace and check search mode `Regular expression` and `. matches newline`.

Then replace the following:

- `^(.*?)Net:` with `Net:` to get writ of everything before the `Net:`
- `^<.*$` with nothing to get writ of lines with no `Net:`
- `,(.*?)$` with nothing to get writ of text after the `Net:`

Your output will then be:

```
Net:5770
Net:5770
```